# Using Row Values as Columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm just starting to learn mySql and am having trouble getting the table that I want.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
name | state | city    
|----------------------------|
bob  | fl    | miami 
bob  | ca    | san francisco
```

and I'm trying to make a table that takes the cities of Bob and turn it into two columns so it would look like this:

```
name     |  FL city    |  CA city
|--------------------------------------|    
bob      |     miami   |  san francisco
```

how would I be able to do this? There are name ids from previous queries that I could use so bob for example is 1.
(also this is my first time posting on stack so apologies for the terrible formatting)
thanks in advance :)

Comment: how many rows are possible more than 2

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 0):

one way if the number of states are limited :

```
select 
 name 
, max(case when state = 'FL' then city end) as "FL city"
, max(case when state = 'CA' then city end) as "CA city"
group by name
```

or using `pivot` otherwise you need to use `dynamic sql`

Answer (score 0):

it is called pivot, to trans dforms rows into columns

> ```
> CREATE TABLE users (
>   `name` VARCHAR(10),
>   `state` VARCHAR(2),
>   `city` VARCHAR(12)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO users
>   (`name`, `state`, `city`)
> VALUES
>   ('Bob', 'FL', 'Miami'),
>   ('Bob', 'CA', 'SanFrancisco'),
>   ('Alice', 'CA', 'SanFrancisco');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> `name`,
> MAX(IF (`state` = 'CA', `city`, NULL)) as 'CA city',
> MAX(IF (`state` = 'FL', `city`, NULL)) as 'FL city'
> FROM users
> GROUP BY `name`
> ```
>
> ```
> name  | CA city      | FL city
> :---- | :----------- | :------
> Bob   | SanFrancisco | Miami  
> Alice | SanFrancisco | null
> ```

> ```
> SET @sql = NULL;
> SELECT
>   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
>                CONCAT('MAX(IF(`state` = "', `state`,'", `city`,"")) AS "',`state`,' city"')
>               ) INTO @sql
> FROM users;
>
>
> SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT `name`,  ', @sql, ' 
>                   FROM users 
>                  GROUP BY `name`
>                  ORDER BY `name`');
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
> ```

> | name | CA city | FL city |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Alice | SanFrancisco |  |
> | Bob | SanFrancisco | Miami |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8354991b62f3ce9d0765b488eda0526d)*